# Problemas com data MYSQL

Tags: mysql, data

Tenho que fazer uma consulta no banco mysql mas estou com um problema na minha query.

No meu banco tenho  3 campos string, sendo um day, month e year. Estes não são datas, e sim varchar. Ok. Não poderei mudar isso pois peguei este banco assim mesmo.
Quero pegar as datas iguais ou maiores do que hoje. O lance que quando ele consulta o proximo mes, ele não pega a data do inicio do mes e sim a data com o dia igual ou maior do que hoje.

```
SELECT *,(str_to_date(CONCAT(agenda.year,'-',agenda.month,'-',agenda.day), '%Y-%m-%d')) as dta 
FROM agenda 
WHERE  agenda.day >= 26 
AND  agenda.month >= 04 
AND  agenda.year >= 2016 
ORDER BY  (str_to_date(CONCAT(agenda.year,'-',agenda.month,'-',agenda.day), '%Y-%m-%d'))  
LIMIT 6
```

Ele me retorna até virar maio, mas dai pega acima do dia 26-05 e não antes.
Existe alguma forma ou função de melhorar isso?
Qualquer ajuda será bem-vinda.
Atenciosamente

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Testa este select.

```
SELECT *,
        (str_to_date(CONCAT(agenda.year,'-',agenda.month,'-',agenda.day), '%Y-%m-%d')) as dta 
from agenda WHERE  agenda.day >= 26 and  "agenda.month >= 04 and  agenda.year >= 2016" 
ORDER BY  (str_to_date(CONCAT(agenda.year,'-',agenda.month,'-',agenda.day), '%Y-%m-%d'))  LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Não rolou. Teintei também selecionar como UNIX_TIMESTAMP e não funcionou